# Check if variable is (defined) not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, undefined

Got confused by this behaviour. I thought doing something like:

```
if (variable name)
{
    ... do this...
}
```

should work. However if the variable is not defined, I just get 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: "variable name, and the else block won't even be executed. For example the following snippet that I got off another StackOverflow question doesn't work when I test it. Any suggestions?

```
if(persons_name) 
{
    var name = persons_name;
} 
else 
{
    var name = "John Doe";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (typeof persons_name !== 'undefined') {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Note that you don't need braces with `typeof`.

Comment: Code like this obfuscates the actual issue of referencing a non-existent variable. And it isn't equivalent to the test for "falsey" values in the question.

Comment: Well the author didn't specify anything about `false` values, but talked about variable existence. If you want to check if a variable is defined, my code is right.

Comment: `if (variable name)` is a test for no "falsey" values, not merely a test for existence or not `undefined`. The `typeof persons_name !== 'undefined'` doesn't deal with the fact that you're trying to incorrectly reference an undeclared variable. It skirts the issue with a hack. A better solution is to heed the information in the error, and declare the variable properly.

Comment: I know that. I'm just saying that the question title "Check if variable is (defined) ..." refers to my solution.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. The title says one thing, while the code says another.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a property, an unqualified name has to be defined before you can use it. So you if you were looking for a global variable persons_name you could write

```
if (window.persons_name)
```

and it would evaluate to undefined if persons_name didn't exist. Alternatively, you can simply declare persons_name if you expect it to exist.

```
var persons_name;
```

This won't change the value of persons_name if it already exists.

Comment: I didn't know that second part.

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = (typeof persons_name !== 'undefined' || !(!!persons_name)) ?
    persons_name :
    'John Doe';
```

Answer (score 0):

by saying `var name;` you define the variable; and by saying `var name = "john doe";` you assign it a value.